# LINQ Select Syntax VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a list of `Tuples` I am trying to run a `Select` and `Where` query on to return a list of `Objects` from the `Tuple.Item5` parameter. In my where clause I am looking to match `Tuple.Item4` to a local variable.

I'm not sure what the VB.NET syntax is for the Select portion, I only know the c# syntax.

Essentially I am trying to select `Tuple.Item5` from my list of tuples where Tuple.Item4 = sCurID. I'm unsure as to what should go in the Select section although in c# I believe it would be `Select(t => t.Item5)`

This is what I have:

```
listObj = listTuples.Select( Unsure What Goes Here ).Where(Function(w) w.Item4 = sCurID)
```

Comment: The same you already use for the Where part

Comment: @Steve Not the same. `Where` takes a function that, given a sequence element, returns a `Boolean` - acts as a filter. `Select` takes a function that, given a sequence element, returns a related object - the object to be collected in the result sequence. These are different return types, and purposes.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Once you apply the `Select` in C# or VB, you have reduced the Tuple to the `Item5` value and can't access `Item4`. Do the `Select` last:

```
Dim listObj = listTuples.Where(Function(t) t.Item4 = sCurId).Select(Function(t) t.Item5)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
listObj = listTuples.Select(Function(t) t.Item5).Where(Function(w) w.Item4 = sCurID).ToList()
```

Comment: The issue is that when I use this my w variable is an Object and not a Tuple, which I'm trying to filter on. It only has the properties of my t.Item5 returned in the select section and not the properties of a tuple item.

Comment: It has t.item5 because you're telling it to. If you want the entire Tuple, you should be fine with just "...Select(Function(t) t)