# How to use Lambda to cast HashSet to string containing only object property

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

I have a HashSet contining class object with properties.

Is there a line of code that I can use to retrieve all values of a property into array ?

```
Class Person
     Dim Name as String
     Dim Age as Integer
     Sub New(pName as String, pAge as Integer)
        Name = pname
        Age = pAge
    end sub

End class

HashPpl As New Generic.HashSet(Of Person)

HashPpl.Add(New Person("Josh", "33"))
HashPpl.Add(New Person("Josh", "35"))
HashPpl.Add(New Person("Ira", "33"))
```

I would like to get the following arrays:

Names containing "Josh", "Josh","Ira"

Ages containing "33","35",33"

How can I do this ?

Thank you !

Comment: Sure, use LINQ's `Select` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0

Comment: `Name` and `Age` are private members, so they're not accessible in a `Select` statement. Otherwise, if they are properties, yes, use Select. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45467568/861716

Comment: Followed by `ToArray` to create an array, though `ToList` is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add the `Age` as a string when your `Sub New` asks for an `Integer`. Use proper Public Properties instead of Private fields. (Dim is private)

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim HashPpl As New Collections.Generic.HashSet(Of Person)
    HashPpl.Add(New Person("Josh", 33))
    HashPpl.Add(New Person("Josh", 35))
    HashPpl.Add(New Person("Ira", 33))
    Dim NameArray = (From p In HashPpl
                     Select p.Name).ToArray
    Dim AgeArray = (From p In HashPpl
                    Select p.Age).ToArray
End Sub

Public Class Person
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Age As Integer

    Sub New(pName As String, pAge As Integer)
        Name = pName
        Age = pAge
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: @Avital The best way to thank someone on Stack Overflow is to accept their answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark to the left of the answer. This will earn me some reps and give you some reps and help future readers.